# PHP RegEx - Get All Digits

Tags: php, regex

I have this code:

```
$string = "123456ABcd9999"; 
$answer = ereg("([0-9]*)", $string, $digits); 
echo $digits[0];
```

This outputs '123456'. I'd like it to output '1234569999' ie. all the digits. How can I achieve this. I've been trying lots of different regex things but can't figure it out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [preg_replace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) for this, `preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $string)` for example.

Answer (score 15):

First, don't use ereg (it's deprecated).  Secondly, why not replace it out:

```
$answer = preg_replace('#\D#', '', $string);
```

Note that `\D` is the inverse of `\d`.  So `\d` matches all decimal numeric characters (0-9), therefore `\D` matches anything that `\d` does not match...